# powershell: split the output and print after the select-string

Tags: powershell, windows-10

First of all, this is my first time with powershell. Everything is quite new. My script looks something like this.

```
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "username@domain.com"
$Password = "password"

$to = "Username @domain.com"

$subject = "daily_check"
$body = (Get-Content 'C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\mylog.log' | Select-String 'string.string1.string2 - Request:') | Out-String

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject = $subject
$message.body = $body
$message.to.add($to)
#$message.cc.add($cc)
$message.from = $username
#$message.attachments.add($attachment)

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.send($message)
```

I get a successful email with all the lines with search string and It looks something like below.

```
INFO    2018-06-01 06:03:01,855 string.string1.string2 - Request: QWERTY- 123 Request: abc- XX1343XX123-01 Request: Type- BB
INFO    2018-06-01 11:06:54,551 string.string1.string2 - Request: QWERTY- 123 Request: abc- XX-12573XX123-00 Request:  Type- BB
INFO    2018-06-01 11:51:50,124 string.string1.string2 - Request: QWERTY- 123 Request: abc- 123XX122233-03 Request:  Type- BB
INFO    2018-06-01 12:20:15,076 string.string1.string2 - Request: QWERTY- 123 Request: abc- XX-12563XX123-00 Request:  Type- BB
INFO    2018-06-01 12:24:25,233 string.string1.string2 - Request: QWERTY- 123 Request: abc- XX-123XX12913-00 Request:  Type- BB
```

But I am expecting my output to look something like this below.

```
2018-06-01 06:03:01, QWERTY- 123 abc- XX1343XX123-01 Type- BB
2018-06-01 11:06:54, QWERTY- 123 abc- XX-12573XX123-00 Type- BB
2018-06-01 11:51:50, QWERTY- 123 abc- 123XX122233-03 Type- BB
2018-06-01 12:20:15, QWERTY- 123 abc- XX-12563XX123-00 Type- BB
2018-06-01 12:24:25, QWERTY- 123 abc- XX-123XX12913-00 Type- BB
```

I was using `-split ' '` and trying to convert each string as a variable and use them but I couldn't. Even if I did there should be a better method to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bruce Payette's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651358/45375) shows you how to *combine* the aspect of *matching* via a regex with token *extraction*, using the `-replace` operator.

To offer an alternative that lets `Select-String` do the matching and then processes the resulting lines via `-split`:

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\mylog.log' |
  Select-String 'string\.string1\.string2 - Request:' |
    ForEach-Object { (-split $_)[1,2,6,7,9,10,12,13] -join ' ' }
```

- `-split` splits each matching line (provided via `ForEach-Object` as `$_`) into an array of tokens by whitespace.
- `[1,2,6,7,9,10,12,13]` then extracts the tokens with index `1`, `2`, ... as an array...
- ... whose elements `-join ' '` joins to form a space-separated list.
- As an aside: note how the `.` chars. in the pattern passed to `Select-String` are escaped as `\.`, so as to ensure that they're treated as *literal* `.` chars, not as the regex *metacharacter* `.`, which matches *any* char.

With your sample input, the above yields:

```
2018-06-01 06:03:01,855 QWERTY- 123 abc- XX1343XX123-01 Type- BB
2018-06-01 11:06:54,551 QWERTY- 123 abc- XX-12573XX123-00 Type- BB
2018-06-01 11:51:50,124 QWERTY- 123 abc- 123XX122233-03 Type- BB
2018-06-01 12:20:15,076 QWERTY- 123 abc- XX-12563XX123-00 Type- BB
2018-06-01 12:24:25,233 QWERTY- 123 abc- XX-123XX12913-00 Type- BB
```

Note: Unlike in your question, the output includes the number following the `,` in the 2nd token; e.g., `06:03:01,855` rather than just `06:03:01,`.
If you really wanted to drop the part after `,`, more work is needed.

---

For reasons unknown, using operators `-split` and `-join` didn't work for the OP, so here's a variant solution that uses near-equivalent .NET methods directly:

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\mylog.log' |
  Select-String 'string\.string1\.string2 - Request:' |
    ForEach-Object { [string]::Join(' ', ([regex]::split($_, '\s+')[1,2,6,7,9,10,12,13])) }
```

Comment: Nice way of combining `-split` with multiple indices. It's not a feature that gets used as often as it should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172524/discussion-between-mklement0-and-ashish308).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) operator and [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6). To convert from the source format to the desired format, you could do something like:

```
$p = "^INFO +([0-9:, -]+)string.string1.string2 - Request: ([a-z-]+) ([0-9]+) Request: ([a-z-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9-]+) Request: (.*$)"
$newstring = $oldstring -replace $p, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6'
```

This code uses a simple (but rather long) regular expression to extract submatches from the source string then replaces the entire string with a new string using back references to substitute the submatches into the string.

Comment: I am not able to use any operator like replace, split and join in my script. Looked into a lot of internet stuff and still scratching my head. Any idea why ?